# Send info message from verify callback to client

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am trying to send the info message that gets set in my verify callback:

Here is the example from passport docs:

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

However if I write my route as:

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
  });
```

That function does not get called with the info message.  At least not that I know of.  I know passport shoves the user into the req, as I can access it from req.user.  Is there a way to access the info message like this.  Or do I need to specify a custom callback?

Which they outline as:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

The part that is confusing is that they outline using a 3rd parameter in the done callback (from verify) that is a message, yet you can only access that if you write a custom callback.  Is that true.

Answer (score 0):

The adopted convention in the `Passport` framework is that the optional `info` object will be available through `req.authInfo`.

This however depends on the used strategy which is responsible for passing it to the Passport framework. For instance, the [`passport-http`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http) strategy does not forward the `info` object to Passport while the `passport-local` does.

Here is how you can then access it in a controller protected by the local strategy :

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function (req, res) {
    if (req.authInfo) {
      // req.authInfo.message will contain your actual message.
    }
  });
```

Comment: What does it pass it to?  Ie since I called done(null, false, {...}) I don't think I get into my route callback.

Comment: If you provide the `done` callback a third arguments, the local-strategy will pass it to the passport framework which will in turn assign it to the `req.authInfo` variable. I have edited my answer with how you can access it later.

Comment: Is there any other information that you would like detailed ?

Comment: 'This however depends on the used strategy which is responsible for passing it to the Passport framework'  I think is what I am running into.  When using the google oauth2 passport plugin my route function is not getting called back if I pass false in the user parameter in my verify callback.

Comment: You don't need to pass a callback to `passport.authenticate` if you just want to receive the `info` object. You can simply do like in your second code snippet example and wait for the authentication to be successful and your next middleware to be called. At this point, use the `req.authInfo` variable to access the third parameter you passed to  `done`. The strategy your are using, `passport-local`, correctly passes the third parameter to Passport so there is no problem with that.